# Object append. Location is random

Tags: append

Whenever I try to append an object the object generates in a totally random location. You'd think it would appear at the location of your 3D cursor. This is not the case. Is there a reason for this or do you think it could possibly be a bug? People suggest that it appears in the location it was saved in from the appended source file, but all the instances of these appended files appear to have the target object(s) around the center, yet when I append the object(s) they appear to be 20, maybe 30 units away in some direction.

Comment: It should appear in the same position it has in the original file.

Comment: it should be in the same position as the original , but the origin point and scale may change

Comment: When you append an object, it will be at the location of where it was in the file you append from. If it isn't that, then it is a bug

Comment: Why is this too broad? It seems to me that the OP was confused by the way blender preserves the position of objects when appending, as @iKlsR pointed out. Why not leave that as an answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: @gandalf3 That's not how I interpreted it. OP says the file appears in a random location every time. Probably has something changed, object origin off etc, rather than list the several possible reasons as to why it might be, best to wait for clarification. The information provided is too vague to provide a sure answer.

Comment: @iKlsR True, I didn't think of that. But wouldn't *Unclear what you're asking* be a better fit?

Comment: @gandalf3 Sorry. I didn't realize how vague it was.

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist Can you share the file you are appending from? Use http://pasteall.org/blend and share the link here.

Comment: @iKlsR I don't really have a specific instance where this is bugging me. It just happens every time I append.

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist Go to _File > Load Factory Settings_ to get everything to the default and try again.